# KMP string-matching algorithm implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, strings

This is Knuth-Morris-Prat algorithm implementation to check if a pattern is present in a larger text, and if it does the algorithm returns the start index of that pattern, else -1. It starts off by computing Longest Common Prefix array, please refer [LCP array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array), and uses that to efficiently avoid redundant pattern matching. I request that my code be reviewed for implementation and naming conventions. For more context about the question please refer, [StrStr()](https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-strstr/)

```
int knuthMorrisPratt(String text, String pattern) {
    if (text == null || pattern == null || text.length() < pattern.length) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (pattern.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int[] lcp = computeLongestCommonPrefixArray(pattern);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < text.length() && j != pattern.length()) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == pattern.charAt(j)) {
            j++;
        }
        else {
            if (j > 0) {
                j = lcp[j - 1];
                continue;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (i - j) <= (text.length() - pattern.length()) ? (i - j) : -1;
}

int[] computeLongestCommonPrefixArray(String pattern) {
    int[] lcp = new int[pattern.length()];
    int len = 0, i = 1;
    while (i < pattern.length()) {
        if (pattern.charAt(i) == pattern.charAt(len)) {
            len++;
            lcp[i] = len;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            if (len != 0) {
                len = lcp[len - 1];
            }
            else {
                lcp[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return lcp;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Comment: As a start: you code totally fails to convey what it is about to the reader. KMP? LCP? WTF? I suggest you start off by renaming you abbrevs to something meaningful and revise the question (as long as there's no answer yet.)

Comment: I find the naming much improved in late revisions (just correct Pratt's name). `implementation […] conventions` _should_ include code documentation (see mtj's comment, too) - there even is a [standard tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide).